# Force redraw of a UIView or CALayer on scale/transform

Tags: ios, uiview, scale, calayer, drawrect

Say you have a `UIView` or a `CALayer` that does its own (vector) drawing, and you want it to remain crisp at any size, even when scaling the view or layer. How can I make it redraw when it is scaled with the `transform` property? Is the only way to do to force a `bounds` change instead of using the `transform`? Or to call `setNeedsDisplay` at every step?

Why do `UIImageView` seem to behave differently (i.e. it seems to always scale its source image appropriately, even when it is scaled with `transform` and the `bounds` doesn't change)? Is it because it's the only case where the `content` property of the underlying `CALayer` is set directly?

Comment: What exactly is the question? When you are dealing with a scalable vector the display will be calculated prior to display while a UIImageView would be simply displaying a rastor image. Unless the content mode is set to scale and the content is larger than the current displayed size it would definitely not look crisp. If you are scaling a rastor'd vector (rendered) then you are basically just scaling the finished product. If you are simply scaling a view that contains a rendered vector then you are scaling an image.

Comment: I know, and this is the problem, I would like `drawRect` to be called repeatedly, instead of just magnifying the initial rasterization. `UIImageView`, on the opposite, doesn't just magnify the pixels of its initial bounds, it uses the full resolution of the source image. I guess it means Core Animation always uses a bitmap in transforms and when `drawRect` is used the bitmap's size is the bounds, but when the content is an image the bitmap's size is the image's size. Which makes me think I could try to use `rasterizationScale` with a value greater than 1....

Answer (score 7):

if `needsDisplayOnBoundsChange` on the `CALayer` is not enough in your case, you can subclass `CALayer` and implement the `+ (BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key` method. Example:

```
+ (BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key {
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"transform"]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return [super needsDisplayForKey:key];
}
```

now your layer should be redrawn everytime the `transform` property changes. This might cause performance issues in animations if your drawing is extensive.

Answer (score 1):

For vector based layers, you can use [CAShapeLayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html%20CAShapeLayer). This specalised layer takes a path and will redraw as needed to keep the layer looking crisp.

Create a `CGPathRef` and assign it to the layer's `path`:

```
shapeLayer.path = myPath;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `self.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.redraw`

Comment: Is there a way to set this on a CALayer itself?

Answer (score 0):

You could manually handle the `setTransform` method of your custom view. A simplified version for handling scaling events could simply be

```
-(void)setTransform:(CGAffineTransform)transform
{
    CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
    bounds.size.width *= transform.a;
    bounds.size.height *= transform.d;
    self.bounds = bounds;
}
```

This would just actually resize your view (and cause a redraw), rather than stretching an image.